# how to address a Flutter 3rd party library's java file in AndroidManifest.xml file?

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, flutter-dependencies

I need to add some receiver configuration tag in my Flutter project's `AndroidManifest.xml` file (in android module) to apply some settings for receiving messages. I use Flutter `sms` library for this purpose and my question is how can I correctly address the `sms` package `SmsReceiver.java` file?
This is my manifest file which '.com.babariviere.sms.SmsReceiver' path is wrong and causes application crash:

```
<receiver android:name=".com.babariviere.sms.SmsReceiver">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
<data
                    android:scheme="sms"
                    android:host="*"
                    android:port="1658" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
```

And this image shows my local `sms` library's path to `SmsReceiver.java` file in Flutter SDK:

[image]

Comment: remove dot before package name i.e. <receiver android:name="com.babariviere.sms.SmsReceiver">

Comment: I did but still crashes